# Reorder columns with EF 4.3 Code-First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Reading both walkthroughs here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

I couldn't find a way to specify the order of the columns in the SQL data table. Looks like the last added property is always mapped to the last column.

Example:

```
public class SampleData {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
}
```

Will create a table with the column order:

**Id | Data2 | Data3**

Updating the class like:

```
public class SampleData {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then running update will update the table into:

**Id | Data2 | Data3 | Data1**

Anyone knows if there's a way to specify the column order when using migrations?

Comment: what's the specific scenario that you're worried about? Working with smaller incremental migrations. You could try edit migrations manually, also try Update-Database -script to see what's going on exactly. Or to manually map the columns in which case I think you could order them as you wish (not confirmed). Would something like that work? I don't exactly follow the 'needs' here like @Ladislav mentioned. Ordering was the 'problem' since the early days as that's not considered a priority I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way except creating new table and moving all data from the old table to new one. The order of columns in the database is not important - you have your application and UI to order columns as you need.

Comment: This a simple database, and I plan on using SQL Management Studio to manually edit the entries at times, that's why order is a concern to me. How certain are you that it's not possible? Anyways, if I don't get another answer for 2 days, going to accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS Docs:

[Change Column Order in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

**...This task cannot be performed using Transact-SQL statements.**